# Would reinstalling Ubuntu solve a software problem?

Tags: dns, reinstall

I am having a rather complicated and confusing software problem relating to DNS and, despite the marvelous advice I have gotten about it, am still stuck. I am increasingly drawn to the idea that I could just store my important files on a thumb drive and reinstall Ubuntu as a solution.

How difficult would this be? Is it likely to fix a software problem? The issue in question can be found here: [Ideas on how to configure DNS properly for Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361167/ideas-on-how-to-configure-dns-properly-for-ubuntu-20-04)

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I thought about suggesting you to reinstall in that question, but I still think this is too drastic solution. I still think it's something simple that could be quite easily fixed if someone could actually have access to your system. However, answering your question - reinstallation should in my opinion definitely fix it. Only be sure not to install that Proton VPN software again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/ check how to uninstall here ~

Disable the kill switch if you have uninstalled the app

The kill switch can be easily disabled from within the official Linux CLI app, but this will not be possible if you have uninstalled the CLI app first without disabling the kill switch. This may result in your system being unable to access the internet. To remove the kill switch after the CLI app has been uninstalled:

a) Identify ProtonVPN connection names by running the command:

nmcli connection show --active

This will display a list of all your system’s active connections.

b) Look for any connections with the pvpn- prefix. This usually includes pvpn-killswitch and pvpn-ipv6leak-protection, and may include pvpn-routed-killswitch. Delete all these connections using the following command:

nmcli connection delete [connection name]

For example:

nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch

c) Re-run the following command to verify that ProtonVPN connections have been deleted:

nmcli connection show --active

If any ProtonVPN connections remain, delete them as described above.